# How to prevent specific symbols from being stripped out by the compiler/linker?

Tags: c++, gcc, linker, clang, symbols

I have a C++ library containing several classes. Some of these classes are used explicitly by an executable and some are not. It seems clang and gcc strip classes not used explicitly from the executable.

How to prevent the compiler/linker from stripping specific symbols? Is there a `pragma` something similar available.

Comment: I remember having a similar real problem similar to this (globals were stripped out and no class constructor called). Solution was to have a dummy function with just this line (if i remember correctly) `void* unused = &my_global` that was called in main. It did nothing but the compiler would consider the global and call it's constructor. Did not find any other solution at that time.

Answer (score 1):

For GCC try disabling DCE flags:

- -fno-dce
- -fno-dse
- -fno-tree-dce
- -fno-tree-dse